# Warm start CPLEX using google or-tools

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, or-tools, warm-start

I have been trying to use the SetHint python API in google or-tools to warm start MIPs and solve it using CPLEX. It looks like my hints are accepted by the SetHint function but I am not sure whether CPLEX is actually using the warm start, the CPLEX output log has nothing related to warm start.

I have set the following parameters in CPLEX through or-tools
`solver.SetSolverSpecificParametersAsString(f"CPLEX Parameter File Version 12.8.0.0 \n CPXPARAM_Advance 1 \n CPXPARAM_MIP_Display 3 \n  CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_RepairTries 100 ")`

Does the SetHint API work with CPLEX? Is there a way to warm start CPLEX using or-tools?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See answer on https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1444

This is not implemented.
I welcome pull requests.

You can have a look at the code in the Gurobi or Scip interface files.